# Strange numerical errors in reduce function in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I am experimenting with map-reduce in mongo and have run into a a numerical problem that has me completely stumped. Given the following map and reduce functions:

```
var map = function(){
    key = "awesome";
    emit(key, {count: 1})
}

var reduce = function(key, values){
    var result = {count: 0};
    values.forEach(function(value) {     
       result.count += value.count;
    }); 

    result.countBy2 = result.count/2
//     result.count = result.count/2

    return result  
}
```

gives the logical

```
"results" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "awesome",
        "value" : {
            "value" : {
            "count" : 7696.0000000000000000,
            "countBy2" : 3848.0000000000000000
        }
    },
```

Uncommenting line in the top code snippet gives very curious output

```
"results" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "awesome",
        "value" : {
            "count" : 98.0000000000000000,
            "countBy2" : 98.0000000000000000
        }
    },
```

Why?

Reversal of the commented lines to keep the object format of the map and reduce commands identical (associative?). .

```
//     result.countBy2 = result.count/2
    result.count = result.count/2
```

Still gives unexpected output

```
"results" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "awesome",
        "value" : {
            "count" : 98.0000000000000000
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Exactly how are you calling the function?

Comment: 'db.stuff.mapReduce(
    map, 
    reduce, 
    { 
        out: { inline: 1 },
        scope: { all:tot },
    }
 );'

Comment: The "mapper" is the problem. You have different "output" from the mapper than the reducer emits as "output" itself. This is the most common mapReduce mistake made, and therefore your likely problem. Show all your code if you do not understand.

Comment: That line would make your reduce function not idempotent. See the reduce function restrictions here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-reduce-cmd

Comment: Has nothing to to with ["idempotent"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) which is a completely different term to the problem here, but at least the link is basicallcy correct. Or more specifically: [Requirements of the reudce function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function) so you don't need to scroll through yourself.

Comment: The idempotent restriction means that: `reduce( key, [ reduce(key, valuesArray) ] ) == reduce( key, valuesArray )`. If you always divide `count` by 2 it's no longer idempotent. You likely want to do the division by 2 in a [finalize function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-finalize-function) instead.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Added all code for you to give full answer

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks for the additional input! Provide an answer below so I can upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `reduce` function includes the line that divides `count` by 2, it violates the idempotent requirement you must adhere to for reduce functions as described in the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function):

> the reduce function must be *idempotent*. Ensure that the following statement is true:
>
> `reduce( key, [ reduce(key, valuesArray) ] ) == reduce( key, valuesArray )`

That basically says that you need to be able to feed the output of one `reduce` call back as input into another call and have the result stay the same.

If you want to perform final processing on the output of your map-reduce, then you can include a [finalize](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-finalize-cmd) function in the options that will only be called once. Depending on what you're ultimately trying to do, that's likely where you should be dividing your count by 2:

```
finalize: function(key, reducedValue) { return { count: reducedValue.count/2 }; }
```